# python requests 403 forbidden but it's used with charles on

Tags: python

- I get 403 forbidden when I use python requests to access .
- However, when I open [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy it works.
- When I open fiddler, I also get 403.

I wanna know why this happens.

```
import requests



def get_test():
    # proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'}
    proxies=None
    url = ""

    my_header={
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6,zh-HK;q=0.5',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',

    }
    rsp = requests.get(url=url,headers=my_header)
    print(rsp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_test()
```

Comment: Python, Charles and Fiddler use different TLS and HTTP frameworks. By fingerprinting all the transmitted data Cloudflare can detect what client you use and block the request if they think it may not belong to a web browser.

Comment: What does this mean? `thanks,i had sovled by httpx with h2 setting` Thanks.

Comment: use python httpx module with http2 protocol to send a request,maybe httpx module has different tls fingerprint

Answer (score 1):

I try to request this page by postman, and also get the result of 403 forbidden. It seems that this website uses Cloudflare's anti-bot page to anti web-scraper which is hard to solve by yourself. This is why 403 forbidden happens.

So I try to use cloudscraper to solve this problem:

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
print(scraper.get("https://www.zolo.ca/").text)
```

but get the exceptions:

```
cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge, This feature is not available in the opensource (free) 
version.
```

It seems that the opensource(free) version of cloudscraper can't solve this problem, and I can't do anythings more.

For more details of cloudscraper, you can see this page or github:

https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/

https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper

Comment: @li blues, glad to see you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you urgently need to scrape the website, you can try Selenium.
Although this method is not elegant enough, but it'll certainly prove equal to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare does checks on your TLS Settings, given that, requests is being detected.
The reason why charles isnt detected its because charles changes your TLS settings.

Additionally, the site may have blocked HTTP/1 which is the unique protocol that requests supports.